# Type reference cannot refer to container 'JQuery'

Tags: jquery, visual-studio, typescript, resharper

Given the following code, ReSharper is giving me the error

```
/// <reference path="../../../../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts"/>

module TypeScript.Framework.Helper.MyModule {
    import Events = Helper.Constants.Events;

    export class MyClass {
        // jQuery variables
        private $title: JQuery; // <-- here it is giving me the error
    }
}
```

> Type reference cannot refer to container 'JQuery'

but the code compiles without any error.

What am I missing or what is ReSharper thinking here?

- Visual Studio 2015 Professional
- TypeScript 1.6
- ReSharper 9.2

Comment: `but the code compiles without any error.` : Just because you get JavaScript emitted doesn't mean there are no errors . More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by a naming issue.
I had a module which was named `TypeScript.Framework.Helper.JQuery` which has been used as type for the property.

Therefore (which in fact is correct) the error-message was shown. I renamed the modules "namespace" and now all errors are gone.